# Is it possible to change current page in the UIPageViewController by using Button?

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I have looked for many different solutions, but none of them can successfully convert the page through the button. Among them, one of the methods I found may be successful, but the system has an unknown error "Unbalanced calls to begin / end appearance transitions", so I would like to know whether there are viable ways to work through the button to convert the page?

Swift 3:

```
public func changeVC(VC: UIViewController) {
        self.setViewControllers([VC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thank you very much:)

Comment: use `protocol` pattern. Where is your button? Is it in the ViewController which is sliding?

Comment: Check  https://github.com/mattneub/pageViewControllerUsingInternalButtons

Comment: Yup. The button is in the ViewController since I have 3 slide in the PageViewController. The button will be call the changeVC method from PageViewController class. Btw, is it impossible to using setViewControllers?

Comment: No its not possible you can check out my answer that is the possible way!

Comment: @AnuragSharma Sorry about that. It seem like some error, but I'm trying...

Comment: @T.Sam Did you get the solution?

Comment: @AnuragSharma Yup. Thanks a lot. Also, I had added some method to do that. :)

Comment: No worries, ready to help anytime!

Comment: @AnuragSharma Hello. Did you know which is the best way to get the height of UIWebView and return to heightForRowAt method? There are some wrong on webViewDidFinishLoad() such as the image are not finished loading when getting the height. Also, the table cell height might be have wrong when scrolling UITableView (each table cell have different height). Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you loading your image in `WebView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create protocol like this in that ViewController where the `UIButton` is

```
import UIKit

protocol welcomeVCdelegate {
    func continueBtnPressed()
}

class welcomeVC: UIViewController {

    var delegate : welcomeVCdelegate?
```

Then in your action call that function you created in `protocol`:

```
@IBAction func continueBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
      self.delegate?.continueBtnPressed()
}
```

Now give the protocol in your main `Class`:

```
class TutorialVC: UIViewController, welcomeVCdelegate {
```

Now create instance of that `class`:

```
var pushVC: welcomeVC!
```

And give the `delegate` where you are `instantiating` :

```
 pushVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "welcomeVC") as! welcomeVC
 pushVC.delegate = self
```

Now define your function here:

```
func continueBtnPressed() {
    print("continueBtnPressed")
      //Push to any view controller from here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use next code:

```
//array with all pages
private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return [
                Utils.newViewController(name: "PhotoOfTheDayViewController"),
                Utils.newViewController(name: "PhotosViewController"),
                Utils.newViewController(name: "PhotosViewController"),
                Utils.newViewController(name: "PhotosViewController"),
                Utils.newViewController(name: "InfoViewController")
    ]
    }();
private var currentIndex : Int!;

//jump to first page
@objc private func home() {
    self.jumptoPage(ind: 0);
}

private func jumptoPage(ind : Int) {

    var index = ind;
    let vc = self.orderedViewControllers.first;
    let direction : UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection!;

    if currentIndex < index {
        direction = .forward;
        index += 1;
    } else {
        direction = .reverse;
        index -= 1;
    }

    if (currentIndex < index) {
        for i in 0 ..< index + 1 {
            if (i == index) {
                self.setViewControllers([vc!], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil);
            } else {
                self.setViewControllers([self.orderedViewControllers[i]], direction: direction, animated: false, completion: nil);
            }
        }
    } else {

        for i in stride(from: currentIndex, to: index - 1, by: -1) {
            if i == index {
                self.setViewControllers([vc!], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil);
            } else {
                self.setViewControllers([self.orderedViewControllers[i]], direction: direction, animated: false, completion: nil);
            }
        }


    }
    currentIndex = ind;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution, which cycles pages in a loop if needed:

```
       var pageIndex:Int?
    var pageControl:UIPageControl = UIPageControl()
    var pages = [UIViewController]()
    var pager:UIPageControl?

    var storyboardref: UIStoryboard {
        get{
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Tutorial", bundle: nil)
        }
    }

    var page1:UIViewController {
        get{
            return storyboardref.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page01")
        }
    }
...
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
...    
        pages.append(page1)
        pages.append(page2)

        setViewControllers([pages[0]], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
               pageControl.numberOfPages = pages.count
        pageControl.currentPage = pageIndex!
    }

   override func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection, animated: Bool, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        super.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: direction, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        pageIndex = pages.index(of: viewControllers![0])
        pageControl.currentPage = pageIndex!
    }    

    func nextPage() {
        let nextIndex = abs((pageIndex! + 1) % pages.count)
        self.setViewControllers([tutorial.pages[nextIndex]], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)    
    }

    func previousPage() {
        let prevIndex = abs((pageIndex! + pages.count - 1) % pages.count)
        self.setViewControllers([pages[prevIndex]], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```